# Take a hash out of its braces

Tags: ruby, hash

Given `bar = {c: 3, d: 4}`, how can you use `bar` to let a code in this format:

```
foo(a: 1, b: 2, some_code_here)
```

express the following?

```
foo(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4)
```

You can splat an array:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
[*a, 4] # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How do you do this with a hash? I tried this:

```
a = {i: 1, j: 2, k: 3}
{*a, l: 4} # => error
```

Answer (score 4):

Use double splat (`**`):

```
a = {i: 1, j: 2, k: 3}
{**a, l: 4} # => {i: 1, j: 2, k: 3, l: 4}
```

Ruby devs: why not use the unused regular splat?

Comment: Regarding your question: `*` triggers `to_a`, whereas `**` triggers `to_hash`. When calling a method, `foo(*a)` is equivalent to `foo([:i, 1], [:j, 2], [:k, 3])`. Changing this behavior would possibly break existing code.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {i: 1, j: 2, k: 3}
a.merge(l: 4) #=> {:i=>1, :j=>2, :k=>3, :l=>4}
```

Comment: You can simplify it to: `a.merge(l: 4)`.